# Templates Not Change using AngularJS & ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, routes, view

When I'm trying to change my 'view/template' using AngularJS in my app, the url changes but the template it's still the Index.cshtml. I think I configured all right but not.
This in my _Layout.cshtml:

```
<body ng-app="application" class="background">

    <div id="ribbon">
        <main>
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here my configuration for my app.js where I'm supposed to put all my controllers:

```
var app = angular.module("application", [
    "ngRoute",
    "ngResource",
    "toastr"
]);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/Index", { templateUrl: "Home/Index", controller: "index-controller" })
        .when("/Main", { templateUrl: "Home/Main", controller: "main-controller" })
        .otherwise({ templateUrl: "Home/Index" });
});
app.controller("index-controller", ["$scope", "$location", function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.goToMainPDS = function() {
        console.log("Loading view...");
        console.log("View Loaded!");
        $location.path("/Main");
    }
}]);
app.controller("main-controller", ($scope) => {
    console.log("Main loaded..!");
})
```

On my Index.cshtml I only have my button with the code:

```
<div class="index" ng-controller="index-controller">
        <div class="index">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="goToMainPDS()">Go to MainPDS</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

I based this application in others I created in the past following the same steps but is not working.

1. In console I'm not getting errors.
2. Whe my application loads the url is "http://localhost:63902/" and when the button is pressed the url changes to "http://localhost:63902/#!/Main" but nothing really happens. The template does not change even if I refresh the page (No errors in console).
3. The only way I can access to that view is if I go through "http://localhost:63902/Home/Main". (Which is incorrect I guess).
4. I do not added a 'ng-view' in any .cshtml file because if I do that, my app starts loading the view again and again with no end.